# How to Search and fetch result from database other than wordpress in wordpress?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, mysqli

I am new to wordpress coding and need some help regarding fetching some data from different database which is not wordpress database and show on wordpress website. Let me make it more clear,

I have two CMS installed 
1. WordPress
2. CRM

In CRM I have some user data which i want to display on wordpress. I searched web but almost each answer is showing retrieving data from wordpress database itself. If you have any way to do it please suggest.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/using-wpdb-to-connect-to-a-separate-database

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an "as is" solution, every database structure of every CRM is different.
You will have to create your own custom database queries, and output the data into variables that you can use to create new queries on the other database.
Next, you will want to format your data and present it into a page.

Comment: Got it, Thank you for your response. Either I have to make custom plugin for it as suggested by D.Saha above, or directly hook into function.php file in wordpress?, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No, you aren't wrong at all.
You can create your own custom functions in functions.php in your Wordpress child theme's directory, and use those hook actions to present the data in whatever position you like into your website!

Answer (score 0):

what i understand from your post is thatyou want to show contents of a different database in your wordpress site. i think i have a solution which is not so good but it should work. 
you can create a custom plugin for your wordpress. sole purpose of that plugin would be fetching data form that db and show it in you wp site. 
make a custom connection in your plugin to connect it with the database you want.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for you input. Somehow I understand where I've to look for.